# getComponents() method symbol not found

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to write a simple GUI and it is my first time using swing. I am trying to use getComponents() for a frame so that I can have access to one of its panels. However, I am getting the error "symbol not found" for the method. I have looked at some other posts about similar issues for getComponent(int i) and they said to import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent, but that did not work for me. Do you have any suggestions/solutions, does anything in my code stick out as blatantly incorrect?

Thanks! My code is below:

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
      {
         Component f = e.getComponent();
         Dimension d = f.getBounds().getSize();
         System.out.println("Width: " + d.getWidth());
         System.out.println("Height: " + d.getHeight());
         Component components[] = f.getComponents();

      }
```

Comment: *"I am trying to use getComponents() for a frame so that I can have access to one of its panels."* If iterating component structures is the answer, it must have been a bloody stupid question. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 2):

getComponents is the method of java.awt.Container, not java.awt.Component
maybe you can try

```
    if(f instanceof Container) {
        Component components[] = ((Container)f).getComponents();
    }
```